# Revoke temp on database from role postgres

Tags: postgresql, permissions, temp-tables

I am trying to create a read-only user in PostgreSQL and I have done so, with the only caveat being that my new read-only user is able to create temporary tables. How?? Why??

I have specifically run:

```
CREATE ROLE read_access LOGIN;

REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM public;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA {schema_name} TO read_access;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA {schema_name} TO read_access;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA {schema_name}
   GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO read_access;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing one permission:

```
REVOKE TEMPORARY ON DATABASE {dbname} FROM PUBLIC;
```

By default, the special role `PUBLIC`, to which everybody automatically belongs, is allowed to create temporary tables.